# Disable Screen Updating, Auto Calculation in Excel from Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

How do I update the `.Application` properties in an Excel workbook from Access VBA?

I'm using Access VBA to export data to Excel, open the file, and format the file (add formulas, etc.).

The code is slow. I want to disable screen updates and change Excel calculations to manual.

`.ScreenUpdating = false` doesn't produce run-time errors, but the screen updates as if the code is ignored.

`.Application.Calculation` produces a run-time error 1004.

```
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = GetObject(Forms!Main!Final_filepath)
XlBook.Activate
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Hide alerts to prevent interruptions when running code
Xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False  '<---- No errors
Xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = False '<---- No errors, but screen updating isn't disabled. 
Xl.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  '<---- Run-Time Error 1004
```

Comment: If `Xl` is an `Excel.Application` (and the code compiles), then `Xl.Application` is redundant. Does `Xl.ScreenUpdating = False` work any better? (not expecting it to, since `Xl.Application` should just point right back at the `Xl` object)

Comment: FWIW `Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` is a rather roundabout way to do `Set Xl = New Excel.Application` (again, not the problem, just pointing it out)

Comment: Some of the code is missing, right? I can't wrap my head around the fact that no workbook is ever opened in the created `Excel.Application` instance, and yet `XlBook` is being assigned just fine... `GetObject` seems a weird way to do this. `Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(Forms!Main!Final_filepath)` would be simpler, it seems.

Comment: I suspect the code that is missing, is holding the answer - most likely, there's an implicit `Excel.Application` instance being created by accident somewhere, somehow (it's very easy to do! simply forget a `Xl.` qualifier somewhere and boom, implicit app reference, and ghost EXCEL.EXE process lingering in Task Manager well after the macro completed).

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for all of your wonderful suggestions. I agree the code I used is a bit clunky, and thanks for the suggestions for a cleaner syntax.  I'm not a formally trained macro writer; I've learned everything in bits and pieces and many, many google searches over the years.  The code I used has been shamelessly copied and Frankensteined together to accomplish the end goals.

Comment: In your third comment, Excel does indeed launch!  The issue was with me actually opening two instances of Excel!!  I was then attempting to apply properties to the Xl instance, which had no open workbook, hence the errors.  I have posted my solution below.  Thanks again for all your great feedback.  People like you who have so generously supported us not-so-clever coders are the reason I've been able to learn as much as I have!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! My original code was actually opening two instances of Excel - "Xl" and "XlBook"
Xl opens as Excel, but without any open workbooks.
XlBook opens as Excel, with the workbook (from file path in the Access form) loaded.

The Xl.Application attempted to apply workbook properties to the Excel window with no workbook loaded.  Hence the run time error for .Calculation.  With no open workbook, the .DisplayAlerts and .ScreenUpdating are meaningless, but didn't create a run-time error - simply the code can't actually apply it to a workbook since no workbook is actually open. I suppose if I then subsequently opened a workbook after the fact, that the properties would be applied?

So, instead of referencing Xl, I referenced XlBook, so the properties could be applied to the open workbook. I removed all references to Xl since I realized it was a redundant Excel window and not needed anyway.

```
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
'Open Excel workbook, and set reference to worksheet
    Set XlBook = GetObject(Forms!main!Final_filepath)
    XlBook.Activate
    XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Disable calcs and screen updating to increase speed
    XlBook.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    XlBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Well done! Verify that the EXCEL.EXE process correctly shuts down - you'll want to invoke `Excel.Application.Quit` via `Xlbook.Application`

Comment: Absolutely am using those lines of code to shut everything down at the end of the sub. :)

Answer (score -1):

You use late binding with no Excel Enum. Try to use -4135 value instead. Or -4105 for xlcalculationAutomatic

Comment: OP is not using late binding. `Dim Xl As Excel.Application` makes `Xl` resolved at compile-time, and for that `Dim` statement to even compile, the Excel type library must be referenced. `CreateObject` has nothing to do with late binding and that instruction could just as well `Set Xl = New Excel.Application`. Every single member call in OP's code is early-bound.

Comment: Actually - not true. There *is* implicit late-binding going on with `Forms!Main!Final_filepath`, since everything after the first bang operator (`!`) can't be resolved at compile-time. `Application.Calculation = 0` (which would be the value of the constant *if* Excel wasn't referenced *and* `Option Explicit` was missing) does not throw error 1004... it happily takes `0` for `xlCalculationManual`.